# SaltStack processing json file

Tags: json, jinja2, salt-stack

Is it possible to process json file by saltstack that is located on minions using states functionality?

I'm sure that it should be possible to do using jinja's functionality, but can't find any information.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`cp.get_file_str`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.get_file_str) is what you need.

You can add the following line for example at the top of your state file and will load the file from the minion as a `json`.

First it will load it as `string` then [`load_json`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.jinja.html#salt.utils.jinja.SerializerExtension) filter will convert the `string` to `json` object so you can handle it like a normal `json`.

```
{% set json_data = salt.cp.get_file_str('/path/to/myfile.json') | load_json %}
```

Note: That line will be compiled before the state modules.